# Centered relative ap div exactly on top

Tags: css

I have a ap div container that is centered in my page.
But on top of my container there a little gap, i would like it to be exactly on top at 0px without that  annoying little gap.

```
#container {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1024px;
height: 1930px;
```

}

i hope someone can answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```